# perform multiprocessing on the same method called two times in each iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, opencv, multiprocessing

I'm trying to optimize the performance of my code which detects and tracks two small cars from two cameras. the cameras provide a bird's-eye view and the two cars drives from one Field of View (FOV) into the other.

Below is the structure of my code

```
While camera1.isOpened and camera2.isOpened: 

 if red_car1_in_FOV1:
   red_centroid, red_centroid_transformed= model.process( passed args)

 elif red_car1_in_FOV2:
   red_centroid, red_centroid_transformed= model.process( passed args)
   
 if blue_car1_in_FOV1:
   blue_centroid, blue_centroid_transformed= model.process( passed args)

 elif blue_car1_in_FOV2:
   blue_centroid, blue_centroid_transformed= model.process( passed args)
```

As you can see that the method `model.process( passed args)` is called two times at the same time (one for the red car and the second for the blue car)

So i believe, i can run each method on a single cpu-core parallely instead of one core.

I made a search on that and came to the package `multiprocessing`which contains methods like `pool()` and `Process()`. However i really got confused in exploiting them in my code.

Any Help or suggestion is appreciated and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be executing these calls over and over again, then it is more efficient to create a process pool of processes to which you can submit "jobs". In this way you are not constantly creating a new process each time you need to do a new unit of work. It is also the easiest way of getting a return value back from another process. You can use either class `Pool` from module `multiprocessing` or class `ProcessPoolExecutor` from module `concurrent.futures`. Here is an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def process(pool):
    """
    pool is a process pool of size 2
    """
    while camera1.isOpened and camera2.isOpened: 
    
        if red_car1_in_FOV1:
            # submit work:
            red_result = pool.apply_async(model.process, args)
        elif red_car1_in_FOV2:
            # submit work:
            red_result = pool.apply_async(model.process, args)
       
        if blue_car1_in_FOV1:
            # submit work:
            blue_result = pool.apply_async(model.process, args)
    
        elif blue_car1_in_FOV2:
            # submit work:
            blue_result = pool.apply_async(model.process, args)

        # wait for completion
        red_centroid, red_centroid_transformed = red_result.get()
        blue_centroid, blue_centroid_transformed = blue_result.get()
        

# required for Windows and other platforms that do not have a fork() call:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We only need a pool size of 2 for this usage:
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        process(pool)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I tried implementing your example on my code and got the follwing error:  AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'apply_asynch'

Comment: I apologize. The method is `apply_async` not `apply_asynch`. I corrected the answer. There is, however, no substitute for looking up the class and understanding the arguments. For example, `args` must be a `list` or `tuple`. So if you only have one argument, e.g. `x`, you could code: `pool.apply_async(model.process, (x,))`

Comment: and if i have many? i mean the method model.process needs up to 13 arguments

Comment: TypeError: apply_async() takes from 2 to 6 positional arguments but 13 were given

Comment: `pool.apply_async(model.process, (arg1, arg2, arg3, ... arg13))`

Comment: File "C:\Users\engjb\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)

TypeError: cannot pickle 'cv2.VideoCapture' object

Comment: You haven't posted enough of your code. But the issue seems to be the following: When it comes to multiprocessing, you cannot just pass as an argument any arbitrary type. The argument has to be able to be transmitted from one address space to the address space of the process that will be doing the work and thus Python has to be able to *serialize* the argument (object). Python uses the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#module-pickle) to do this. You may be out of luck: Python does not how to *pickle* that type.